# Planos cartesianos em Python

Tags: python, imagem, gráfico

Boa noite, boa tarde e bom dia. Eu tenho 15 anos e estou estudando sobre equações de segundo grau, plano cartesiano e funções. Por causa disso, fiz um código para calcular as raízes, coordenadas do vértice, gráfico e imagem. As únicas partes que não estou conseguindo fazer é o gráfico e a imagem que não tenho ideia de como fazer, se alguém puder me ajudar fico muito agradecido. Muito obrigado desde já.

segue o código abaixo:

```
import math

print('-' * 30, ' Coeficientes ', '-' * 30)
valorA = int(input('Insira o coeficiente de A: '))
valorB = int(input('Insira o coeficiente de B: '))
valorC = int(input('Insira o coeficiente de C: '))

print('-' * 30, ' Raízes ', '-' * 30)
delta = math.pow(valorB, 2) - (4 * valorA * valorC)
x1 = (-valorB + math.sqrt(delta)) / 2 * valorA
x2 = (-valorB - math.sqrt(delta)) / 2 * valorA
print('Raízes: {:.0f} e {:.0f}'.format(x1, x2))

print('-' * 30, ' Coordenada das vértices ', '-' * 30)
Xv = -valorB / (2 * valorA)
Yv = valorA * math.pow(Xv, 2) + valorB * Xv + valorC
print('V({:.0f}; {:.0f})'.format(Xv, Yv))
```

Comment: Primeiro verifique a equação no [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) e depois utilize o [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/simple_plot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-simple-plot-py) para plotar o gráfico. Comparando com o resultado do wolfram, se estiver correto quer dizer que você programou corretamente... Caso contrário, revise seu código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sugiro usar esta library [MatPlotlib](https://matplotlib.org) para plotagem de gráficos em Python.

[Documentação](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) Matplotlib

Caso não tenha familiariedade com o inglês, há outros sites na internet que te ajudam com essa library.

Esta [série](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZfnPkkLCA0&list=PLPOyk_fKVcz7ASvdAXg_pxVrVgiUdWTSi) de 15 videos pode ser um ótimo começo.

Comment: obrigado, valeu pela ajuda maninho!